# How to use UV4L to realize WebRTC on Raspberry Pi？

Tags: server, uv4l, webrtc

The browser on RPi does not support WebRTC, so I use UV4L, and UV4L realizes WebRTC .

At the same time Streaming Server can support peer to peer real time connection over LAN, but how to make RPi connect to remote room server (with signalling server & CoTurn server)?

Maybe the Streaming Server module for UV4L can not be configured.

Answer (score 1):

p2p with rpi uv4l is not possible using browsers as browsers on rpi ( chromium and firefox ) cannot fetch the local media stream ( i don't know exactly why but i know they can't ) .

So for inter-network scenarios (such as involving firewall and NAT ) instead of making a p2p connection go for centralized connection .

Use a MCU on cloud such as janus and stream from rpi to janus on port using gst 1.0 and vp8enc .

View the stream from janus at the same port from outside clients .